# Add vertical line to LiveCharts.WinForms.CartesianChart

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls, livecharts

Below is my LiveChart.WinForms.CartesianChart and I am wondering how I can add a vertical line to the chart below - for example I would like to add a black vertical line (with a tooltip) at the point Aug 21 and wondering how I can do this?

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
        cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(new Axis
        {
            Labels = myDateLabels,
            Separator = new LiveCharts.Wpf.Separator { Step = 1 },
            LabelsRotation = 270
        });

        cartesianChart1.AxisY.Add(new Axis
        {
        });
        cartesianChart1.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Bottom;

        var axisSection = new AxisSection
        {
            Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black,
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            Value = 2
        };

        cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(new Axis
        {
            Sections = new SectionsCollection
            {
                axisSection
            }
        });

        SeriesCollection series = new SeriesCollection();

        series.Add(new LineSeries { Title = "Sign Ups", Values = signUpsValues, Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue, Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent });

        cartesianChart1.Series = series;
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add the following code: modify the value of `Value` according to your situation.

```
var axisSection = new AxisSection {
    Stroke=Brushes.Black,//colocr
    StrokeThickness=1,
    Value=2,//Modify this.
};

cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(new Axis {
            Sections=new SectionsCollection
         {
             axisSection         
        }
});
```

Output:

[image]

If you have questions about this, please add a comment below.

Comment: I used `LiveCharts` and `LiveCharts.Wpf` in the `Winforms` .

Comment: This is what I tried doing but the code you provided doesn't seem to do anything - my chart still appears the same as in the question

Comment: Did you modify the value of `value`? After modification, put the above code into the build function. If possible, please paste your code, and I will help you modify it. After the modification as shown in the figure, I have the vertical line. Is your request as shown in my picture?

Comment: It's best to paste all your code, I don't know where our code is different.

Comment: Modify the value of value and confirm whether the table names are the same.

Comment: My request is exactly as shown in your picture - I edited my question to show the code I have tried to use (I only included one of the series for simplicity)

Comment: I have tried changing the value of value for example to 1, 3 etc but the same thing - no change to the picture I originally posted

Comment: Have you tried to change to the same name as the label? For example, Aug21? I will continue to follow up tomorrow.

Comment: It is working now - the vertical line is appearing on the graph - do you know how I can create a tooltip for it? For example when hovering over the line I'd want the tooltip to be "update"

Comment: I have tried many methods, and it seems that it is very difficult to meet the requirements you need. You may need to rewrite the control yourself. If you can accept my answer, I will thank you very much.

Comment: Because your data is static. It seems that you can directly add a `label` and other controls at a certain position, and bind a `tooltip` to achieve a slightly lower effect.

Comment: So there is actually a database call used to determine how many vertical lines there is - is there code which can generate a certain number of labels (based on the data call) or do I have to manually add one to the control using toolbox?

Comment: Could you tell me which `database call`? You may need to do more research on custom operations, I have no luck.